# How to test react native screen UI on different screen from one mobile

Tags: react-native, user-interface, responsive-design

I am new to react native. my question is. what is smart way to test your react native screen UI on different mobile size screen with only one mobile. please help thanks

Comment: If you're on chrome inspect element has an option to change screen sizes. You can also use browserstacks.com

Comment: not for react js i want it for react native

Comment: ok fine thanks but is any free way available